# How to see traffic being routed between 2 Instances from my Load Balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, amazon-elb, aws-auto-scaling

I currently have a Load Balancer that routes traffic between Instances created from my Auto Scaling Group.

For example when 2 Instances are launched from my ASG scaling, what are some ways to go abouts demonstrating traffic being routed from my Load Balancer across these 2 Instances?

Comment: Does it work? Or are you trying to debug a problem? Why do you wan to "demonstrate" it -- wouldn't the fact that it is _working_ demonstrate that it is being routed?

Comment: Configure ELB Logging on your load balancer and you'll have a log of each of the load balancer requests, which backend IP they hit, the status code of the response, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can enable application load balancer access logs and then it will start capturing all the traffic and put it in the S3 bucket. it will show all the details for each request with many attributes including source IP,host, any error, request status and etc

Or you can check after that cloudwatch -> log group and there it will create a new folder of this log.

[image]